# Variable value won't increment by 1 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var countWrong = 0;
(Button1, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6).addEventListener('click', () => {
    countWrong += 1;
});
console.log(countWrong)
```

I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong. When the buttons are clicked I want to increment 1 to `countWrong`.

Comment: Put console.log(countWrong) inside the handler of the click event.

Comment: The only time you output the value of `countWrong` is before anything has ever been added to it.  If you observe the value of `countWrong` *after* adding to it, what happens?

Comment: what are Button1, Button3...? are they classes, ids?

Comment: they are ids ---

Comment: You can't assign a listener to multiple buttons like that. You'll either need to use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/), or add a listener to each button separately - maybe by adding them to an array and using `forEach`.

Comment: What Andy said + also you can't just use IDs to assign eventListeners to. You have to assign it to the actual nodes (html-elements). You can first get them (for example by ID: getElementById('Button1') and then store them in variables and/or assign your eventListeners to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

> ```
> (Button1, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6).addEventListener
> ```

You can't call a method on multiple objects like that. I assume you want something like:

```
[Button1, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6].forEach(b => 
  b.addEventListener('click', () => {
      countWrong += 1;
  })
);
```

EDIT: I assumed `Button...` where variables, but if they are IDs, you'll need to look them up first, maybe like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#Button1, #Button3, #Button4, #Button5, #Button6").forEach( ... )
```

Also `console.log(countWrong)` will always display `0`, because the event handlers won't have been called yet.

Comment: How am i supposed to call the event handlers?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need with jquery

```
var countWrong = 0;
$('#Button1, #Button3, #Button4, #Button5, #Button6').on('click', () => {
    countWrong += 1;
    console.log(countWrong)
});
```

And the console.log() has to be inside your onclick function otherwise your log will only give you the initial value 0 once before any button was pressed

Comment: This is using jQuery.

Comment: I know but jquery is still js, I'm just giving him another option to do this without changing much of his original code, since most ppl know how to use jquery

Comment: It was not a criticism. I just wanted to point it out to the OP. If they didn't know basic JS syntax, I'd assume they'd not know jQuery.

Comment: @RoToRa it's allright, the main reason I'm giving this option is because this question had like 4 different answers already with pure js solutions, rather than repeating the same answer somebody else made I'm just giving a different formula for the OP or whoever might need it if they are facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have written the right code however you see the wrong results.
Because, you are printing the `countWrong` only once after initialising it.
So when you initialise for the first time, it's value will be zero and it prints it.
And when ou click the buttons, the value of that variable will be updated however you won't be able to see because the `console.log` present in outer code has already been executed ( but the value is updating ).

And your logic of binding the events for multiple ids is not as same as you wrote, change a bit.
try this :

```
var countWrong = 0;
['Button1', 'Button3', 'Button4', 'Button5', 'Button6'].forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', () => {
        countWrong += 1;
        console.log(countWrong)
    });
});
```

Comment: This won't work. You are calling `addEventListener` on a string. You could insert `.map(document.getElementById)` between array and the `.forEach()`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment you can't assign an event listener to multiple elements like that. The other answers have covered iterating over the buttons with `forEach` - here's an example with [`event delegation`](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/).

Add *one* listener to a parent container which catches events as they "bubble" up the DOM from its children (the buttons). Within the handler check that the clicked element is a button (and has a "count" class), and then increase/log the count.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

let count = 0;

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('count')) {
      console.log(++count);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button { border-radius: 5px; }
.count { background-color: lightgreen; }
.count:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
Green buttons increase the count

<section class="buttons">
  <button type="button" class="count">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="count">Button 3</button>
  <button type="button">Button 4</button>
</section>
```